# MVC custom filter, invoke ASP.NET pipeline event manually for unit test

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, events, protected

```
public abstract class MyControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // do some magic
    }
}
```

All of my controllers inherit from `MyControllerBase`. The problem is that now I can't unit test certain methods because the filter sets some authorisation/logic flags which influence  code path.

Is there any way to manually trigger `OnActionExecuting`? How does the pipeline trigger these events?

**EDIT:** to show a little more the idea behind this design in response to comments. I basically have something like this:

```
public abstract class MyControllerBase : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        UserProperties = 
             _userService
                .GetUserProperties(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

        ViewBag.UserProperties = UserProperties;
    }

    public UserProperties { get; private set; }

    public bool CheckSomethingAboutUser()
    {
         return UserProperties != null 
            && UserProperties.IsAuthorisedToPerformThisAction;
    }

    // ... etc, other methods for querying UserProperties
}
```

So now anywhere in `View` or `Controller` I can get details of the current user, what is their email, what authorisation they have, which department they work for etc.

Example:

```
public class PurchasingController : MyControllerBase 
{
    public ActionResult RaisePurchaseOrder(Item item)
    {
        // can use UserProperties from base class to determine correct action...

        if (UserProperties.CanRaiseOrders)

        if (UserProperties.Department == item.AllocatedDepartment)
    }
}
```

So this design works really nice, but as you can see testing the above action is difficult as I can't directly manipulate the `UserProperties` in the test set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you're suppose to override `OnActionExecuting` like that in MCV, normally I make an [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx)

```
public class SomeMagicAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

    }
}
```

Then your class:

```
[SomeMagic]
public abstract class MyControllerBase : Controller
{

}
```

Then in your unit test you can just do

```
var magic = new SomeMagicAttribute();
var simulatedContext = new ActionExecutingContext();
magic.OnActionExecuting(simulatedContext);
```

Comment: The problem here is that in the `OnActionExecuting` event I write some flags to `ViewBag` and to public properties in `MyControllerBase`. The idea is that these values are now available everywhere, in all controllers and views. My memory is a little vague, but I think I chose my design because I couldn't see how that was possible using a custom `ActionFilterAttribute`. Would you have any ideas?

Comment: Could you post some of the magic your `OnActionExecuting` does? - at least for setting stuff in the viewbag you can do `filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.magic = 42;`

Comment: I have updated the question to show the idea behind the design. `OnActionExecuting` doesn't do anything clever, it just accesses some user information that I want to make available globally. Your comments are greatly appreciated if you think I'm doing it the wrong way.

Comment: No, you're not doing it the wrong way, in fact I just checked the MVC project I'm working on, and we're doing it pretty similar. - Anyway, from your code sample, it seems like you don't really need the `ActionExecutingContext`, you so you can just fill the UserProperties variable with `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` in your base constructor right?

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately as `HttpContext` is null in the controller constructor.

Comment: Oh.. I didnt know that. Then, another solution, you could just make your property like `public UserProperties { get { return _userService.GetUserProperties(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name); }}`

Comment: but then how would I set ViewBag also?

Comment: like shown in my answer, you could do that with an `ActionFilterAttribute`. But you could just leave it in the `OnActionExecuting` too right? Or do you use things from the viewbag elsewhere in your controller / your unit-tests? Because that would seem kind of weird too